# Convert MySQL Select query into an Update query

Tags: mysql

I am using MySql to update the last line ( `Member_id = 140`) of database users of a column `Sponsor_Parent` with the result of a Selection of the last line of the Column (`Sponsor_username = Test91`) to find their `Sponsor_username`

That is the Last line `Sponsor_username` is `Test91` and want to update with the a selection of the value of their sponsor `username = Test1A`

Thus putting in `Test1A` into `Sponsor_Parent` of last line `Member_id = 140`

My `Select` works fine but I cannot convert it into a working `Update` query.

These Select queries work fine:

```sql
SELECT member_id, username, sponsor_username from users WHERE username = 'Test91'
```

This is a Manual Direct Input using the last line value.
Returns: `15, Test91, Test1A`

Now I take it a step further and select the value which works fine

```
SELECT member_id, username, sponsor_username from users WHERE username = (Select sponsor_username From users ORDER BY member_id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Returns: `15, Test91, Test1A`

This also works with a manual variation

```
Select Member_id, username, sponsor_username From users Where sponsor_username = 'Test91' in (sponsor_username) AND 'Test91' in (username)
```

Returns: `15, Test91, Test1A`

When I use this Command as an `Update`

```
Update users Set sponsor_parent = (SELECT sponsor_username from users WHERE username = (Select sponsor_username From users ORDER BY member_id DESC LIMIT 1))
```

I get the Error:

> #1093 - Table 'users' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

So if I get rid of the duplicate users with a kind of `Join` command

```
Update users s1 Set sponsor_parent = (SELECT s1.sponsor_username WHERE s1.username = (Select s1.sponsor_username ORDER BY s1.member_id DESC LIMIT 1))
```

It updates every row with a `Null` value

Not sure how to get the last line updated with `Sponsors`, Sponser name in `Sponsor_parent` column

User Table Layout:

| Member_id | username | firstname | lastname | sponsor_id | sponsor_username | sponsor_new | Sponsor_parent | Spon_matched |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | Test91 | My | Test91 | 0 | Test1A | 0 | 0 |  |
| 140 | TestD3 | My | TestD3 | 15 | Test91 | 4 | 0 |  |

[User Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze7nI.png)

What I want is in the Last line of every Insert is the Parent name of the Sponsor_username So when a new user joins ( Username ) the Introducer is listed in (Sponsor_Username ) and if there are two generations list the Introducer of the Introducer. ( ie is the Introducers Parent Username listed in Sponsor_parent ) I am looking for an Update / Select command

[Final Layout desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aANTa.png)

So at Member 15 Test1A introduces Test91 who goes on to Introduce testD3 at Member ID 140. So I want the grandparent username if possible on any new member username, otherwise Null entry Insert into Sponsor_parent Column on the last line entry

Problem I am facing is I am selecting the Grandparent name and then trying to update the last line with the selection all from within the same table.

OK I nearly solved my own question
This works
update users as u1
inner join (
SELECT sponsor_username from users where username = (SELECT sponsor_username from users ORDER BY member_id DESC LIMIT 1)) as u2
set u1.sponsor_parent = u2.sponsor_username
where member_id = "140"

All I need to do now is replace the "140" last line Member_id with something like "ORDER BY member_id DESC LIMIT 1" but I can't get the syntax right to update the last line only

Comment: Please provide your table structure and example of desired output.

Comment: Can you show me your expected output?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Solved the Update command of the Sponsors Sponsor entry

The Problem I had was Doing an Update with a Select command using two references to the same table in the command
This caused a Duplicate problem giving this error
#1093 - Table 'users' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

I had to select the last line from a table 'users' and use this to lookup the sponsor name in another column from the same table and find out who there sponsor was in order to update a new column in the same table.

So what I have with this Query command is a Nested Inner join command including a Vertical lookup (Vlookup) using the last line value command - ORDER BY member_id DESC LIMIT 1

The final solution Update command is
update users as u1
inner join (
SELECT sponsor_username from users where username = (SELECT sponsor_username from users ORDER BY member_id DESC LIMIT 1)) as u2
inner join (
SELECT member_id from Users Where member_id = member_id ORDER BY member_id DESC LIMIT 1) as u3
ON u1.member_id = u3.member_id
set u1.sponsor_parent = u2.sponsor_username